# Download file Report JotForm using API in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, jotform

I Have Issue with Azure Data Factory, when i tried to download file from API and sink to storage blob , it always error

this is sample api key : https://api.jotform.com/report/222961798189071?apikey=68ba253ddf42c986053f083619fe7591

and this is report link to download : https://www.jotform.com/excel/222961798189071

I've tried using HTTP connector to Pipeline source Copy data
[image]

this is connection source
[image]

but when i run the pipepline it always error
"*ErrorCode=HttpInvalidUrlAddress,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Http Url Address 'https://www.jotform.com/excel/222961798189071https://api.jotform.com/report/222961798189071?apikey=68ba253ddf42c986053f083619fe7591' is invalid.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,*'"

[image]

or am i missing some step?

Comment: What is the file type of the report?

Comment: @Aswin Excel File from jot form api

Answer (score 0):

Excel file has a lot of limitations in ADF  and **it does not support copy activity sink** and **data flow sink** as well.

**To resolve the error. Please follow below steps:**

I took both source and sink as **binary** to perform copy activity.

**Step 1:** **Source as HTTP**

[image]

- Make sure to provide proper linked service with base URL:

[image]

[image]

**Step 2: Sink as binary from blob**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**This is my blob storage after Succeed. You can download and verify excel file data.**

[image]

Comment: i follow your step by step, but this error occured :ErrorCode=HttpRequestFailedWithUnauthorizedError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Http request failed with status code 401 Unauthorized, usually this is caused by invalid credentials, please check your activity settings.
Request URL: https://www.jotform.com/excel/222961798189071.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.,Source=System,'

Comment: but when i tried to test connection the HTTP conection is succesfull

Comment: @Kucluk, please [check](https://i.imgur.com/dm1qvo3.png) your **username** and **password** update the same in [linked service](https://i.imgur.com/mVBSWxz.png)

Comment: yes i used email, and password are correct.  and when i test conecction is succes

Comment: @kucluk, I got same error: (401) after test connection is success. I just solved this error by adding **username** and **password**. you can try once **choose**  : **Authentication type** as **Anonymous**